# Multidimensional arrays in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

Is there any way to create a multidinensional array that contains arrays of different lengths (similar to nesting arrays of different lengths in python).

Because if I were to declare a variable `Dim accounts(2,2) As Integer` all 1D arrays at each dimension have the same length. Is there any way to create an array so that this is not the case?

e.g The above code would create an array like this:
`[[0,0],[0,0]]`
but would it be possible to create this:
`[[0,0],[0,0,0]]`

Apologies for the poor explanation but I cannot think of any better ways to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to a jagged array. And yes, .net supports this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

And here's a quick example:

http://www.startvbdotnet.com/language/arrays.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use jagged arrays in .Net, but it might be better to use collections instead. That would make it easier to add & remove entries.

Try `List(Of List(Of Integer))`

Answer (score 0):

See [Collection and Array Initializers in Visual Basic 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee358704.aspx).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.